# Maps search box autocomplete with callback JS function?

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, location-search

I am struggling with using a callback for my Google Maps API.
I am trying to have a Goolge Maps autocomplete search box and collect the Lat and Long for the searched location. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49249650/5660293) that works really well, but sometimes the search box won't load the location suggestions. I've found that this might be caused by the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` that I use. Instead I've found that I need to use a callback in my script. I tried that but now the search box won't load any suggestions anymore. Below is what I have now. Am i doing something wrong? Thanks a million for your help and suggestions!

**In functions.php**

```
<?php
//ENQUE SCRIPTS
function my_enqueue() {
    // First register script
    // Google maps API
    wp_register_script('googlemaps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initialize');
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery') );
    
    // Then enqueue script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'googlemaps' ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script' ); 
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
?>
```

**In custom.js**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    function initialize() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
          google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
              var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
              if (!place.geometry) {
                window.alert("Select a suggestion from the list");
                return;
              }

              document.getElementById('city2').value = place.name;
              document.getElementById('cityLat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
              document.getElementById('cityLng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
          });
      }
      //Window load does not seem to always work?
      //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}); //Close document ready
```

**In html**

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />  
<input type="hidden" id="city2" name="city2" />
<input type="hidden" id="cityLat" name="cityLat" />
<input type="hidden" id="cityLng" name="cityLng" />
```

Comment: 1) Anything in the console? 2) `ajax-script` doesn't depends on `googlemaps` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nothing in the console... I tried adding dependencies but that didn't work...

Comment: Oh sorry, it says "initialize is not a function" in the console. How come it is not a function?

Comment: If it's not the script enqueue fault, then the problem is out of the WordPress scope. Try to ask the question on a appropriate site.

Comment: Looks like the mess with JavaScript: nothing declares there to mention jQuery somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your js file:

```
    function robbte_map_initialize() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
          google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
              var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
              if (!place.geometry) {
                window.alert("Select a suggestion from the list");
                return;
              }

              document.getElementById('city2').value = place.name;
              document.getElementById('cityLat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
              document.getElementById('cityLng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
          });
      }

      jQuery(document).ready (robbte_map_initialize);
```

Comment: Simple document ready seems to work, thanks!